# Excel VBA - Split Sheets of Saved excel Files

Tags: excel, vba, split

I need some help with excel VBA code,

I have split a file into seperate files based on a column (Country) using the below VBA code. This produces around 40 seperate files,

Example data

[image]

Produces:

Australia.xslx

Costa Rica.xslx

Tanzania.xslx

United Kingdom.xslx

Is there a way to then split each of the files by another column (with row entries 1,2,3), so that each file has three sheets without having to open each file and running a macro for each file?

[image: Australia Data] ->[image] - [image] - [image]

[image]

VBA - Split Sheet

```
Sub Split_Sheet()
Const FirstC As String = "A" '1st column
Const LastC As String = "C" 'last column
Const sCol As String = "A" '<<< Column to Split data by
Const shN As String = "Countries" '<<< Source Sheet
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(shN)
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Long, c As Long, x As Long, r1 As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
r = ws.Range(FirstC & ":" & LastC).Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

 c = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column + 2

Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, FirstC), ws.Cells(r, LastC))

ws.Range(sCol & ":" & sCol).Copy
ws.Cells(1, c).PasteSpecial xlValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ws.Cells(1, c).Resize(r).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
r1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Cells(1, c).Resize(r1).Sort Key1:=ws.Cells(1, c), Header:=xlYes
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For x = 2 To r1
For Each ws1 In Sheets
If ws1.Name = ws.Cells(x, c) Then ws1.Delete
Next
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
For x = 2 To r1
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, sCol), ws.Cells(r, sCol)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ws.Cells(x, c)
Set ws1 = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
ws1.Name = ws.Cells(x, c).Value
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next x
With ws
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Cells(1, c).Resize(r).ClearContents
.Activate
.Range("A1").Select
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

VBA - Save Each File

```
Sub SaveEachWorksheet()

Dim FPath As String

FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    ws.Copy

    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\"ws.Name & ".xlsx"

    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: How many lines in the file?

Comment: Overall there are around 29k rows (which then vary per country line file)

Comment: Try the approach below - if it's too slow I will tweak it a bit...

Comment: Actually I think it may be failing because it is too slow (has worked intermittently) Would be super grateful if you could help me to make it more efficient!! @Tim Williams

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - took a different approach.  Tested with 20k records/15 countries, 5 categories.

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub SplitToFiles()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet, rngData As Range, data, country, category, ws As Worksheet
    Dim col As New Collection, wb, dict As Object, r As Long, k, categories As Collection
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Countries")
    Set rngData = wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'assuming no empty rows/columns in data
    data = rngData.Value
    
    'collect unique countries (as dictionary keys) and categories (in collections, by country)
    For r = 2 To UBound(data, 1)
        country = data(r, 1)
        category = data(r, 2)
        If Len(country) > 0 And Len(category) > 0 Then
            If Not dict.exists(country) Then dict.Add country, New Collection
            On Error Resume Next                 'ignore error
            dict(country).Add category, category 'add the category (unique using key)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next r
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each country In dict
        Set categories = dict(country)
        Set wb = GetWorkbook(country, dict(country)) 'create workbook/sheets for this country
        For Each category In categories
            Debug.Print country, category
            ResetFilters wsData
            With rngData
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=country
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=category
                .Columns(2).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            End With
            With wb.Worksheets(category).Range("A1")
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Next category
        wb.Close savechanges:=True
    Next country
    ResetFilters wsData
End Sub


'Creates workbook and worksheets as needed
Function GetWorkbook(country, categories As Collection)
    Dim wb As Workbook, i As Long
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) 'new wb with one sheet
    wb.Sheets(1).Name = categories(1)
    For i = 2 To categories.Count 'name the rest of the sheets (if any)
        wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)).Name = categories(i)
    Next i
    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & country & ".xlsx"
    Set GetWorkbook = wb
End Function

Sub ResetFilters(ws As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @TimWilliams ! Really appreciate the above - I have attempted to run it on my data and it works well for the first two entries (Australia and Costa Rica) but falls over for subsequent countries with 'ws.Name = category already taken' Do you know how I can get around this?

Comment: See new code above - I think it's going to be much faster and avoids the bug in my original code.

Comment: This code does seem to make sense but still keeps falling over at 
wb.Sheets(1).Name = categories(1)
with Invalid Procedure Call or Argument - Do you know what could be causing this?
Thanks again!